# These two codes should do exactly the same thing, but the first one doesn't work as I expect

Tags: python, class, oop, artificial-intelligence, crossover

**Python**

Please explain why these two codes work differently..
Actually I am trying to make kind of AI where in initial generations the individuals will go in random directions. For keeping the code simple I have provided some random *directions* in *Brain* myself.

There is an *Individual* class that gives a brain to the individual. It also has a function that returns a child with EXACTLY the same brain (means same directions to go in) as the parent.

I have two codes:

**First:** When some directions is changed in the parent, the same thing is changed in the child too (or if changed in child, it gets changed in parent too) which I don't want to happen.

**Second:** This one is not completely mine (and that's why I don't really know why it works) but it works fine. Some direction changed in parent is not changed in the child and vice-versa.

Please someone explain me the difference and why first one didn't work. I would really appreciate your answer.

First one:

```
class Brain():
    def __init__(self):
        self.directions = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5]]

class Individual():
    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = Brain()

    def getChild(self):
        child = Individual()
        child.brain = self.brain
        return child

parent = Individual()
child = parent.getChild()

parent.brain.directions[0] = [5, 2]

print(parent.brain.directions)
print(child.brain.directions)
```

> [ [5, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5] ]
>
> [ [5, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5] ]

Second one:

```
class Brain():
    def __init__(self):
        self.directions = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5]]

    def clone(self):
        clone = Brain()
        for i, j in enumerate(self.directions):
            clone.directions[i] = j
        return clone

class Individual():
    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = Brain()

    def getChild(self):
        child = Individual()
        child.brain = self.brain.clone()
        return child

parent = Individual()
child = parent.getChild()

parent.brain.directions[0] = [5, 2]

print(parent.brain.directions)
print(child.brain.directions)
```

> [ [5, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5] ]
>
> [ [1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5] ]

Comment: This is called shallow copy and deep copy. In `clone()` you've written a deep copy.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting some idea, but is assignment same as shallow copying?

Comment: If you print the object you can see weather its the same object, or a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, setting `child.brain = self.brain` doesn't do what you're expecting. That is a shallow copy, meaning that it just creates a new pointer to the same instance of `Brain()`. So now `child.brain` and `self.brain` both point to the same `Brain()` in memory.

In the second code, you are making a deep copy. Thus, you are actually allocating another `Brain()` in memory. Now `child.brain` and `parent.brain` point to their own separate instance of a `Brain()` in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I even read about this in detail [here](https://medium.com/@thawsitt/assignment-vs-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-python-f70c2f0ebd86) just if someone needs

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are referring same object.
Try adding following print statement in first case.

```
print (id(parent.brain))
print (id(child.brain))
```

Have new reference for Brain() in first case. you can see how it handles.

```
class Brain():
    def __init__(self):
        self.directions = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 4], [1, 5]]

class Individual():
    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = Brain()

    def getChild(self):
        child = Individual()
        child.brain = Brain()
        return child

parent = Individual()
child = parent.getChild()

parent.brain.directions[0] = [5, 2]

print(parent.brain.directions)
print(child.brain.directions)
```